# During upgrade, database raised exception 9002

Tags: sql-server, database, docker, docker-machine

I am trying to run MSSQL container on an Ubuntu host using Docker. The container starts but in few seconds it crashes.

Below is the container logs which points to a file system or a disk issue:

```
2017-10-06 07:23:10.95 Server      Query Store settings initialized    
with enabled = 1, 
2017-10-06 07:23:10.99 spid6s      Starting up    
database 'master'. 
2017-10-06 07:23:11.00 Server      Software Usage    Metrics is disabled. 
2017-10-06 07:23:12.20 spid6s      The tail of    the log for database master is being rewritten to match the new    sector size of 4096 bytes.  3072 bytes at offset 418816 in file    /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf will be written. 
2017-10-06    07:23:13.71 spid6s      Converting database 'master' from version 862    to the current version 869. 
2017-10-06 07:23:13.72 spid6s         Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 862 to    version 863. 
2017-10-06 07:23:14.51 spid6s      Database 'master'    running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864. 
2017-10-06    07:23:14.83 spid6s      Error: 17053, Severity: 16, State: 1.    
2017-10-06 07:23:14.83 spid6s      /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf:    Operating system error 31(A device attached to the system is not    functioning.) encountered. 
2017-10-06 07:23:15.84 spid6s      Error:    928, Severity: 20, State: 1. 
2017-10-06 07:23:15.84 spid6s         During upgrade, database raised exception 9002, severity 17, state 0,    address 0000000484CD26DE. Use the exception number to determine the    cause. 
2017-10-06 07:23:15.86 spid6s      Error: 9002, Severity: 17,    State: 0. 
2017-10-06 07:23:15.86 spid6s      The transaction log for    database 'master' is full due to 'NOTHING'.
```

Below is my docker configuration

```
prashanthadiyodi@dev-ubuntu14:~$ docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 12
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-129-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 7.798GiB
Name: dev-ubuntu14
ID: FALX:S7M7:H6RN:7JQF:FZM7:ZL2T:RCRN:RGON:XYU6:WEEO:2JLC:TBAH
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

I am running the below command to start the container

```
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=adi1982' -p 1433:1433 -d --name mssqlcon -v mydata:/data  microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-GA
```

Please note that I have used different variations of specifying the data partitions to use but had no luck.

Need help from the community to understand the root cause.

Comment: Please edit your post and use code blocks for information you paste from the terminal. The logs and configuration are unreadable in their current form, which makes it much harder for anybody to help you.

Comment: @sergiu - Thanks for helping edit my post

Comment: @user2709587 you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Error 9002

The error 9002 happens when the transaction log becomes full. So you may want to free disk space on the disk drive that contains the transaction log file.

See: [Troubleshoot a Full Transaction Log (SQL Server Error 9002)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/troubleshoot-a-full-transaction-log-sql-server-error-9002?view=sql-server-2017).

#### Check password requirements

Your password (such as `adi1982`) doesn't meet the [complexity requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017). So try adding a non-alphanumeric characters such as exclamation point (`!`).

#### Check logs

To check for errors, run: `docker logs ID` (where `ID` is container ID from `docker ps`).